# Equivalence relation that has exactly two equivalence classes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I just want to see if I am understanding this correctly.

I have to create an equivalence relation on 1,2,3 that has exactly two equivalence classes. So I came up with S = {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (1,2), (2,1)}.

So the equivalence classes would be [1] = {1, 2}, [2] = {2, 1}, [3] = {3} which works. [1] == [2] so theres one equivalence class and the other is [3]. There is exactly two equivalence classes. Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct; your example works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is of course the relation $R$ using the function
$$
f(x)=-1.5x^2+6.5x-4
$$
and then defined by
$$
aRb\iff f(b)-f(a)\text{ is even}
$$

---

A maybe simpler, but actually quite similar one is given by
$$
aRb\iff b-a\text{ is even}
$$
which has classes $[1]=\{1,3\}$ and $[2]=\{2\}$.